# I want to store datetime in peewee.DateTimeField(), I use datetime.datetime.now() in that field as default but it can't work

Tags: python, datetime, peewee

**this code cannot work and give json serializable error**

```
  class Bank(peewee.Model): // create Bank table
        bank_id     = peewee.PrimaryKeyField()
        bank_name   = peewee.CharField()
        account_no  = peewee.CharField()
        ifc_code    = peewee.CharField()
        swift_code  = peewee.CharField(null = True)
        modify_date = peewee.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now(),formats=['%Y-%m-%d'])/*date in yyyy-mm-dd formate*/
        status      = peewee.IntegerField(default = 0)

        class Meta:
            database = db
```

Comment: The answers to this question should NEVER be used. The answerer is providing something that only appears to work, but has a critical problem in that it only evaluates the default value once, at import-time. PLEASE just store it as a proper datetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This answer is very incorrect** - please see my answer below (@coleifer).

---

The default date that you are providing is not a datetime object. Rather it's a string!

```
modify_date = peewee.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

`type(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))` --> **`str`**

You can pass default current datetime object like this:

```
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
need_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')

modify_date = peewee.DateTimeField(default=need_date)
```

or

```
peewee.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

Comment: TypeError: datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 30, 0, 0) is not JSON serializable

Comment: datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 30, 0, 0)  to  str is ok

Comment: Look at your output section

Comment: datetime can‘t directly output json， to str output

Comment: whoa whoa whoa. This is so wrong. That callable is evaluated at module import time. Store your data as a proper datetime by setting default=datetime.datetime.now (NO PARENTHESES). Then handle converting it to a string when you need to serialize.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like non-timezone aware datetimes work fine, so if you're using UTC then you can store `datetime.utcnow()` as that returns the current UTC date and time with tzinfo None i.e. as a "naive" datetime object.

I found this solution to store and retrieve the timezone aware field as text, however it's not ideal as the datetime object isn't being stored.

```
from datetime import datetime
from peewee import *


class TimestampTzField(Field):
    """
    A timestamp field that supports a timezone by serializing the value
    with isoformat.
    """

    field_type = "TEXT"

    def db_value(self, value: datetime) -> str:
        if value:
            return value.isoformat()

    def python_value(self, value: str) -> str:
        if value:
            return datetime.fromisoformat(value)
```

https://compileandrun.com/python-peewee-timezone-aware-datetime/

Comment: From @coleifer's answer above I can see now that it's better to store the DateTime as an object. However there is an issue with using timezones as per: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/1427. How can we resolve this if we want to store as UTC without using naive datetime?

Comment: I've noticed it works if using `datetime.datetime.utcnow` which returns the current UTC date and time, with tzinfo None. I.e. the current UTC date and time, as a naive datetime object https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow

Comment: I've also noticed that there's a DateTimeTZ for Postgres in the Postgresql extensions, however no equivalent for SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a date, use the DateField. Also, the default needs to be a callable -- in other words, leave OFF the parentheses!

```
class Bank(peewee.Model): // create Bank table
    bank_id     = peewee.PrimaryKeyField()
    bank_name   = peewee.CharField()
    account_no  = peewee.CharField()
    ifc_code    = peewee.CharField()
    swift_code  = peewee.CharField(null = True)
    modify_date = peewee.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    status      = peewee.IntegerField(default = 0)

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

When it comes time to serialize this as Json, just use a custom json formatter that can handle python datetime.date objects. This is the proper way. You should always store your data using the appropriate format and worry about presentation (and serialization) in another layer.

It is very simple to extend Python's json serializer to handle unsupported types:

```
def convert_date(o):
    if isinstance(o, datetime.date):
        return o.__str__()

json.dumps(my_obj, default=convert_date)
```

Comment: I still do not know why someone voted down this answer. This is the answer of the creator of peewee. LoL